# Button not pop up modal box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've create a code where if I click the button it supposed to pop up the modal box, but it is not working

here's the [JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rudy94/3279y6zj/)

```
    <form><br>
<h1 style="text-align: center; color:red;">LOGIN</h1>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME" id="name"><br><br>
    <input type="password" name="matrixno" placeholder="MATRIX NO" id="matrix"><br><br><br>
<button id="myBtn" style="cursor:pointer; margin-right: 4.5cm; padding: 7px 16px;">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="modalBox" class="modal">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">x</span>
         <p id="show"></p>
         <p id="show1"></p>
      <a href="page2.html" id="myBtn">Click me!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Open the console window and check for errors.

Comment: Also, remember JS is case-sensitive. `element.onClick` is not `element.onclick`.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `s` in your call to `getElementByClassName`. It should be `getElementsByClassName`.

Additionally, look at where you're assigning the event listener to `onClick` vs `onclick`. The property name is `onclick` and is case sensitive.

Finally, your button does not have a `type` set, which means it will attempt to submit the form. You can prevent this a few ways, but the easiest (IMHO) is to set `type="button"`.

Like Johnny mentioned, it is always a good idea to check the console for errors, that would have at least gotten you the first issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one issue is that you're using `document.getElementByClassName("close")[0]` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]`. It's plural - `getElements` - rather than `getElement`.

As Johnny pointed out, you also need to be careful with casing. The onclick event will not function as you have it. It should be `btn.onclick = function()`, rather than `btn.onClick = function()`.

Comment: And a button in a form with try and post so event.preventDefault() will be needed

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle, check and find the difference [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3279y6zj/2/)

First of all check the code , use `document.getElementByClassName("close")[0]`instead of`document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]`

, i have commented that code as your primary was to open modal.

Then your `onClick` should be changed to `onclick`.
Also your `<button>` is trying to submit the form so I have also added a new button to find the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You've had a couple of people tell you how to fix the modal box you already have, so I thought I'd show you how to make a different sort, that requires no Javascript at all.

```css
.modal-state {
  display: none;
}
.modal-body {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: opacity 400ms cubic-bezier(.24,.34,.12,.89);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.modal-state:checked ~ .modal-body {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modal-outside {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 0;
}
.modal-inside {
  padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  max-width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  z-index: 1;
}
.modal-footer {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}
/* pretty span buttons */
.button {
  background-color: tomato;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input id="modal-state" type="checkbox" class="modal-state">
<div class="modal-body">
  <label class="modal-outside" for="modal-state"></label>
  <div class="modal-inside">
    This is an example of a modal box using CSS only. You'd be supprised how easy it is to do. Just a few lines (42 lines of CSS) and no need for any JS, though you can still use it if you like.
    <br>
    <br>
    <b>Open:</b>
    <br>document.querySelector('.modal-state').checked = true
    <br>
    <b>Close:</b>
    <br>document.querySelector('.modal-state').checked = false
    <br>
    <b>Toggle:</b>
    <br>document.querySelector('.modal-state').checked = !document.querySelector('.modal-state').checked
    <br>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <hr>
      <label for="modal-state"><span class="button">Close</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<label for="modal-state"><span class="button">Open</span>
</label>
```

This uses a hidden checkbox called `.modal-state` to store whether the modal box is open or not.

You can use a label with the `for` attribute set to the checkboxes ID `modal-state` as a way to change the state from anywhere.

There are ways you trigger it with JS if you want, and I've included the commands in the example.

I hope you find this helpful, or at the very least interesting.

Comment: I find this very interesting!! .. thanks for this .. but this assessment required me to use html, css, and javascript .. this coding is so good! .. you really know how to use css dude .. thanks for this .. I've a few question for your coding .. 1st) what is this "document.querySelector" .. is this a JS? or what .. 2nd) why u use this symbol --> ' '  for modal-state

Comment: document.querySelector is indeed javascript it lets you uses CSS selectors to select elements so I typed .modal-state (the dot meaning class). What symbol do you mean sorry?

Comment: I mean this symbol --> ' ' .. is it similar to --> " " ??

Comment: Oh, you mean in the javascript example? Yes ' and " both basically do the same thing. I just mix and match depending on where my fingers feel like typing ;-)

Comment: ahhhhhh .. I got it ;) .. by the way bro, can u look at my coding? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rudy94/hmbpv6gn/)